# Limiting how much data fits in memory using Python and how to deal when data does not fit in memory?

Tags: python-2.7, memory-management, numpy

I want to perform a test wherein if I have a dataset of 500 MB, I want to read only 100 MB of that data. This is just an example. In general if my dataset is of size x, I want to be able to read only x/k amount of it.

The data is in the form numpy array. The code flow would be:

```
data = pickle.load(open('test.data', 'rb'))
nrows = data.shape[0]
ncols = data.shape[1]
sketch = np.zeros((k, ncols) #k << n
for item in data:
    Do Something
```

I want to simulate streaming model when data does not fit in memory. Streaming model is when you have only one pass over data.

How does python handle datasets when they don't fit in memory. For e.g if my ram is 4gb and the above pickle data is 40 GB, what happens

Comment: don't use pickle for numpy, you should use hdf5.

Comment: Python will throw a `MemoryError` exception if you try and unpickle something that won't fit into core memory. [Memory-mapped arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) can be useful for processing large datasets that won't fit in RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Since I agree with them, I will merge comments from @HYRY and @ali_m: if your data isn't able to fit in memory, the easiest way to deal with it "out of core". Meaning the data is on disk but a software layer allows you to interact with it almost as if was in memory. There is a solution built-in to numpy: [memory mapping](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html). Another really good package is [pytables](http://www.pytables.org/). The first one stores data as a binary file and numpy lays on top of the file instead of on top of a block of RAM. You can then do anything you want with the data including operations across the array. The other one requires an HDF5 file, and supports some operations out of core, and they are blazing fast, and a couple of reduction operations, but you are more limited. On the other hand, HDF5 is a very popular format accessible from many other languages, so that is a really good choice.

Comment: Using pytables can I specify, I want only one record or 100 records in RAM?